# C++ decltype in Java

Tags: java

Is there something similar to C++ decltype operator in Java? 
For example, in C++ it's possible to write:

```
    long double i = 33.0;
    decltype(i) j = i * 2;   // j type is long double
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there isn't.  You must either explicitly provide the type, or use the `var` keyword to automatically infer `j`'s type (introduced in Java 10).